# C# OpenXML (Word) Table AutoFit to Window

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Open a Word (2007/2010) document that has a table in it, select the table and right click, select AutoFit-->AutoFit to Window

How can I implement this action in C# using the OpenXML SDK 2.5?

Comment: I already tried to use the productivity tool with no luck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set the width of the table to 100% of the page, or 5000 fiftieths-of-a-percent.

```
Table table = ...

TableWidth width = table.GetDescendents<TableWidth>().First();
width.Width = "5000";
width.Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct;
```

Comment: 5000 fiftieths-of-a-percent 