# Insert table into word by openxml and how to set the width fit to the word

Tags: openxml

I want to create a word file by openxml and insert a table in it. Now I dont't know how to set the width of the grid to fit to the word file. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025424/c-sharp-openxml-word-table-autofit-to-window

Comment: Are you using the Open XML SDK? If yes, you should click on "edit" and add that tag to the question so that it appears in the correct lists.

Comment: @user2155362 Don't forget to vote up/accept answers if they resolved your problem, seeing your new question Jpad's answer helped you

Answer (score 7):

The table width can be set by the second line of code.

The rest is just included to show how you can append the properties to the table

```
TableProperties tblProps = new TableProperties();

var tableWidth = new TableWidth() { Width = "5000", Type =TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };
tblProps.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);

table.Append(tblProps);
```

Comment: According to the site guidelines (check the Help Center), Answers that contain only code or links are "low quality" and subject to deletion. Your answer can become a valuable resource on the site if you include some explanation about how it addresses the problem stated in the Question. Also, you need to be careful: the person asking the question has not specified the Open XML SDK is being used, so you're making an assumption that could invalidate your answer :-)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: If you look at the link the poster sent in his comment then it is clear that the person  asking the question was using the open xml sdk

Comment: I have added an explanation but it was very self evident from the code. Otherwise I would have added an explanation